# searching for a word in database

Tags: sql, search

I am storing questions and answers in a database like FAQs and i want to allow the user to search. so for example the user will enter "how to bla bla bla" and i will search for every word and neglect the common words like "the", "to", "is" ....

so this was my idea, do you think its a good one or you suggest something better?
and how to search for a single word in a sql database? do i have to get a dataset from the table for example and iterate on it and get the questions i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lucine.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) api should help, it's great open source api provided by apache that index documents you provide and search in that documents depending on your criteria

Comment: i am searching inside only one table and on only two fields. do you think it worth using this library because i cant understand how to use it and i see it is kinda complicated?
or it will be better in performance?

Comment: Lucine has a great performance as I know, because it indexes data, It has API in Java and in .net, and here is .net examples, I thnik it is not complicated. There are LINQ to Lucine.net API to if you use .net. http://smartasses.be/2008/04/15/minimal-lucenenet-example/ http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx http://www.codeplex.com/linqtolucene

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server you might want to look into Full Text Searching. See the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of creating an index has been solved many times.

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.net) is pretty widely used and can index your tables.
Many of the major databases have full text indexing capabilities or add-ons that you can find.

All of these will require some configuration and headscratching on your part, but should work well enough.

If you've got a pretty small problem, building your own keyword index is a fun project to undertake. Google "inverted index" or "text index" to get started and break out the hash tables....

Comment: i am searching inside only one table and on only two fields. do you think it worth using this library because i cant understand how to use it and i see it is kinda complicated?
or it will be better in performance?

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle you have [Oracle Text](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/text/index.html). It allows you to make powerful searches for text on tables.